# How to display grouped variable count in each row

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to show the count of a given rating for a given month in each rating's row for the data below. This would mean that on rows 0 and 3 there would be a 2 since there are two 10 ratings given in month 1.

```
test = {'Rating': [10,9,8,10,8,6,4,3,0,7,2,5], 'Month': [1,2,3,1,3,2,1,2,3,1,2,3]}
test_df = pd.DataFrame(data=test)
```

I have tried the following but it didn't help much:

```
test_df['Rating_totals'] = test_df.groupby(['Month'])['Rating'].count()
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `value_counts()`:

```
test_df.value_counts()
```

To sort the results by month and rating:

```
total_rankings = test_df[['Month', 'Rating']].value_counts().sort_index()
```

Use pandas `apply` to add the total count for each row as a new column to `test_df`:

```
test_df['total_rankings'] = test_df.apply(lambda row: total_rankings.loc[row['Month', row['Ratings']], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks! 

How can I create a new column in my df where each row has the count display? In other words, how can I create a column that would display 2 for rating 10 in month 0 and 3?

Comment: For some reason it's not matching totals by month to each rating. Instead I'm getting the first ten rows populated with totals for all months combined by rating.

Comment: Strange, for me it is working as expected. Can you please show the full code you are using along with the results you get?

Comment: Noticed that a bracket was missing. Works great now. Thank you so much!